# EF Core 2.0 scaffold-dbcontext Find ConnectionString in another project

Tags: entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-2.0

I am using the EF Core 2.0 CLI command **scaffold-dbcontext** to reverse engineer poco classes from an existing DB (database first). The project that contains my appsettings.json file with the **ConnectionString** is different from the project that holds the poco classes generated by scaffold-dbcontext.

How can I get the scaffold-dbcontext command to find the ConnectionString in the appsettings.json file of another project?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of the time of this post, it doesn't appear that the scaffold-dbcontext command supports a appsettings.json connection string lookup. In other words, you must explicitly type the full connection string using the scaffold-dbcontext cli syntax:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "Server=(localdb)\ProjectsV13;Database=MyDbName;Trusted_Connection=True;" -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Model -Context "MyDbContextName" -DataAnnotations -Force -Project MyEntitiesProject -StartupProject MyEntitiesProject
```

Not directly related to the OP, but just as a word to the wise... using the `StartupProject` option is helpful so you don't have to switch the Startup Project in Visual Studio to your entities project (e.g., MyEntitiesProject) in order to run the scaffold-dbcontext command.

There's a good link detailing the scaffold-dbcontext command options [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/cli/powershell).

Also be sure to have the following packages installed in your project in order to use the scaffold-dbcontext command in the nuget package manager console:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design
```

Comment: for dotnet CLI users `--startup-project` and `--project`, docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/cli/dotnet#target-project-and-startup-project

Answer (score 25):

As stated in [this](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/10432#issuecomment-398714520) you can now specify your connection string to be named, which looks like `name=MyConnectionString`. The name of your connection string corresponds with the one defined in your `appsettings.json`. Example:

```
Scaffold-DbContext  -Connection name=MyDB -Provider Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

where in `appsettings.json` you have something like this:

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "MyDB": Server=mydb.database.windows.net;Database=mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;Encrypt=True;"
}
```

Comment: coming in clutch with the simplicity.

Answer (score 3):

For me both answers were useful. I wanted to generate the context in another project, so it was required to specify the startup project and select the project where I had to generate the context. So I use:

```
Scaffold-DbContext -Connection name=DefaultConnectionString -OutputDir DataModel -StartupProject NameofTheProject.API Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using -StartupProject option in Scaffold-DbContext and making startup project reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design package (only caveat).

*Example*

**Project DB**: will contain EFCore autogenerated classes

**Project API**: contains appsettings.json with connection strings (must reference Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design)

**Execute in the package manager Console**

Scaffold-DbContext -Connection "name=<connection string name>" -Provider Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -OutputDir EFModels -Context <DbContext class name> **-Project DB -StartupProject API** -Force

[if something is wrong you can have detailed logging with -Verbose option]